# Python parse CSV with delimiters messed with punctuation

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file with comma-delimiter, 5 columns, first and second columns - text. In this text sometimes a lot commas, also sometimes at the end of the row there are multiple commas in a row.

```
Type,Category,Count,LAT,LON
xxx,yyy/yyy,362,36.0121,-106.65801,,,
zz zz,zz -zz,xxx,2539,35.39353,-106.501916,,,
cc,dd,527,35.330102,-106.505023
...
```

Appreciate any help how to fix it efficiently.

For now I stopped on removing all ending "," in a row file before reading.

Next: maybe somehow check from right to left - if there is string after numerical bloc - consider first part as `Category`, all other to the beginning of the row - remove comma.

Any ideas?

**UPD**: Pattern - looks like excessive commas always only in first column. So just need to read from the right to left 4 columns and everything else combine to first column "Type".

Answer (score 1):

Starting in example from

```
x,x,x,yyy/yyy,362,36.0121,-106.65801,,,
z,z zz,zz -zz,xxx,2539,35.39353,-106.501916,,,
c,c,dd,527,35.330102,-106.505023
```

and running

```
<input.txt sed -r 's/^(.+?),([^,]+),([0-9]+),(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+),(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(,{0,})$/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5/'
```

you will have this TSV

```
+---------------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
| x,x,x         | yyy/yyy | 362  | 36.0121   | -106.65801  |
| z,z zz,zz -zz | xxx     | 2539 | 35.39353  | -106.501916 |
| c,c           | dd      | 527  | 35.330102 | -106.505023 |
+---------------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
```

I have applied this regex https://regex101.com/r/uc9Agd/2

It's simply sed and not Python, but you can use the same regex in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over the file? Whoever generated it should have escaped the string using quotes (commas in between quotes should be ignored by the [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)). Or they could choose to use a character that isn't in the data as the column delimiter (like the pipe symbol `|`).

If you don't have control over generating the file, I'm not sure the best way to do it. If you know where the commas appear you might be able to write a script that first finds the pattern (via regex) you're looking for and escapes them like I reference above.

Comment: No control(   Additional commas and text without quotes.  Pattern - almost always additional commas only in first row.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to export the csv again or are there enough rows to update manually? Usually, when there's commas on the csv file, it's common practice for the text to be surrounded by double-quotes.

If it's not possible, I would do the following:

1. Split into four columns, where the first would be all text;
2. Get a list of Types or Categories (whichever is easier to get) and split the column into two according to what substring exists in the list

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

For now I've made this solution:
It's slow, not elegant, but working.

@Aborruso's regex solution also great.

```
COLUMNAMOUNT = 5 #
with open(os.path.join('data', 'messed.csv')) as csv, open('new.csv','w') as result:
        for line in csv:
            line = line[:-1].rstrip(',') + line[-1]
            line = line.split(',')
            l = len(line)
            if l > COLUMNAMOUNT:
                line[l-COLUMNAMOUNT] = ''.join(line[:l-COLUMNAMOUNT+1])
            result.write(','.join(line[l-COLUMNAMOUNT:]))
```